# spring mvc:resources makes annotated controllers not available

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am having problem using mvc:resources in spring 3.1 configuration.

Initially i was working on the project that integrates spring 3.0, JPA, on tomcat 6. 
On tomcat 6 server, i used the following servlet-mapping in web.xml to access static contents(css,js and png etc) from my application.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am not sure if it is best practice but it worked fine on tomcat6 environment. It doesnt work  on tomcat 7. So i switched to spring 3.1 to use the mvc:resources element in applicationContext. I changed xml namespaces for 3.1 and added the two lines in applicationContext.xml.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**"/>
```

The whole application worked very well before I added the above two lines of configuration. But now all annotated controllers are not detected by the framework. I dont have index.jsp or any welcome files in application root and I mapped root requests "/" to annotated RootController.java. So the appliation home page is not even loaded.

When i check around the net in search of the solutions, i found out that mvc:annotation-driven replaces some default bean configuration that i think is implicitly defined by the framework. I found some solutions that works for some people in this forum which is to explicitly define some bean configuration by myself. 
I tried adding the following two lines

```
<bean class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/> 
<bean class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>
```

But unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. I am not sure if it is the real problem that i am facing now ,so here is my  applicationContext.xml for you to check my current configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yewintko.uog.emailcampaignmanager">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**"/>
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" /> 
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>   

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="EmailCampaignManager"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.platform}"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="${database.showSql}"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${database.generateDdl}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am very new to spring and have no idea which configuration is missing in my applicationContext. Please someone help me if you have a little free time. If you need more information please let me know.

regards
Yewint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your annotated controllers are not getting scanned by Spring is because of following line in your applicationContext.xml file.

```
<context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
```

Please remove that line and it will resolve your issue. Hope this helps you cheers.

Comment: hi Japs 
sorry i accidentally deleted above comment. it works and thank u very much. btw can u please explain why removing that line solve the problem?

Comment: Because it is for excluding filter for some package or annotated classes you want to exclude from spring scanning. That is why removing it is solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

puts your controller's at `http://localhost:8080/{warname}/static/{controller}`
however mapping your resource servlet is mapped on the same url.
You can fix this by changing either of the mappings.
since i assume i want your resource servlet to point to the /static/* path, all you should have to do is change the servlet to /

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then your controllers are at `http://localhost:8080/{warname}/{controller}`
and your static content is at `http://localhost:8080/{warname}/static/`

try to think of the mvc:resources as a controller with a method anotated with /static/**
it will capture all requests you try and do to your services.

For performance reasons in production environments it's better to use a regular webserver to serve static content.

Comment: Hi G-Man
thanks for ur reply. Ur answers is an alternative way to access static contents. But i am having problem of using new feature mvc:resource that was introduced in 3.0.4. Thanks again